# Streamlit: plot multiple lines in graph

Tags: python-3.x, linechart, streamlit

I'm new to Streamlit and trying to plot a graph with the widget st.line_chart.

I have a dictionary that I filled with data from different files with :

```
listFilesTemp = glob.glob(folder+ '/*.npy')
nbFilesTemp = len(listFilesTemp)    

TempDict = {}

for j in range(len(listFilesTemp)):       
    dataExtract = np.load(listFilesTemp[j]) 
    filename = listFilesTemp[j].replace(folderTemp + '\\', '')       
    TempDict[filename] = dataExtract
```

So I now have a dictionary composed of string keys and for each an array of values.

I would like to plot data from several files on 1 interactive graph, but I must be missing something from the documentation, I don't manage to succeed. I tried :

```
for i in TempDict:
        st.line_chart(data=TempDict[i], x=None, y=None)
```

But it displays 1 graph/file. It seems that I have to modify the x or y parameters of this function, I tried a couple of things but I have not managed to do so far. How can I say to streamlit to plot several arrays from my dict in one graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use plotly in combination with [st.plotly_chart()](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.plotly_chart).

The following code uses plotly express library, adapt it to your dictionary:

```
st.plotly_chart(px.line(TempDict, x="<Xvar>" ,y=["yvar1","yvar2","yvarX"]), use_container_width=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try out Plotly in combination with streamlit. You can add traces to the chart like shown [here](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/)
and then display them with
`st.plotly_chart(fig)`